# PHP mail () function I don't receive the mail

Tags: php, smtp

I successfully sent mail, mail function returns boolean true but i don't receive it I also try PEAR Mail and NET_SMTP but I don't receive it I use hMailServer and I set [mail function]

```
; For Win32 only.
;http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
;http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
; For Win32 only.
http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = test@localhost.com
```

my hMailServer log is

```
"SMTPD" 5444    65  "2016-06-13 19:12:43.491"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: MAIL FROM:<test@localhost.com>"
"SMTPD" 5444    65  "2016-06-13 19:12:43.497"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250 OK"
"SMTPD" 4120    65  "2016-06-13 19:12:43.498"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: RCPT TO:<run@gmail.com>"
"SMTPD" 4120    65  "2016-06-13 19:12:43.503"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250 OK"
"SMTPD" 8080    65  "2016-06-13 19:12:43.504"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: DATA"
"SMTPD" 8080    65  "2016-06-13 19:12:43.542"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 354 OK, send."
"SMTPD" 3144    65  "2016-06-13 19:12:43.626"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250 Queued (0.080 seconds)"
"SMTPD" 4120    65  "2016-06-13 19:12:43.628"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"SMTPD" 4120    65  "2016-06-13 19:12:43.629"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 221 goodbye"
```